# How to model a Recurring Query based calendar with dependencies on resources like recrurring tasks and timekeeping

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, mongodb

I'm storing calendar events as a table/list of events. I want to change this to something more flexible to perform easier queries-

For e.g. This design will let me ask, what I want to be able to ask  `Calendar.Employee().Between("Jan 1 2014").and("July 4 2014").Get("TimeSheets John").All("Recurring").TwoWeeks();`

or

`Calendar.Resource().Between("2014").and("2017").Get("Conf Room Boston").All("Recurring").ToList();`

Could you please share a framework or a DB model for the DB data table/s. And, how the server side object would map-build that recurring event into an object model- so that

1. Query tasks within a time frame, for e.g. last week?
2. **Query tasks based on recurring models, (every 2 weeks)**
3. It can persist recurring events - with dependencies on TaskID, Conference Room etc

In this following Q&A someone recommended templates. what a template would look like in a DB table. [saw this SO but did not help much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992187/best-way-to-develop-manage-design-recurring-tasks-calendar)

Can you also give me some guidance on if this is the wrong class/object to use -- [I'm using Calendar Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Would I be better served with DDay object?

Answer (score 2):

How about using your existing objects with LINQ?

One of your queries might look like this:

```
CalendarItems.Where(c=> 
  c.Date.Year >= 2014 && 
  c.Date.Year <= 2017 && 
  c.Room = "Conf Room Boston" &&
  c.isRecurring == true && 
  c.RecurringType == RecurringTypes.BiWeekly);
```

For your database interface, I'd recommend Entity Framework.  That will seamlessly convert between tables and the regular C# classes your used to.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I was seeking ideas/feedback on how these time events & recurring models in the DB are better/reusably solved. So, what objects/frameworks are used to support this. I have a big right now, calendars seem to be very complex for home grown stuff. _I want to gut and replace it with a library and better DB model._

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question.  If you're seeking a library that has these function built in, I don't have any suggestions.